# Excel: Nested IF and INDEX MATCH returning #N/A

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 4 sheets. I'm trying to create a function in the first sheet that checks for a value in a column in the next sheet. If the value isnt found there, it looks in a similar column in the next sheet and so on. I have the following function, and it works when looking in sheets Dummy1 and Dummy2 but returns #N/A when looking in Dummy3. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
=IF(INDEX(Dummy1!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy1!$B$3:$B$2473,0))<>0,
INDEX(Dummy1!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy1!$B$3:$B$2473,0)),
IF(INDEX(Dummy2!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy2!$B$3:$B$2473,0))<>0,
INDEX(Dummy2!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy2!$B$3:$B$2473,0)),
INDEX(Dummy3!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy3!$B$3:$B$2473,0))))
```

Comment: it means it can't find in all 3 dummy sheets ?

Comment: If it's definitely in Dummy3 is it a number formatted as text while B1 is an actual number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the match formula does not find a match, say in Dummy1, it will return #N/A. In turn, this will abort the if function, rather than return a false and continue looking in Dummy2.

Try to wrap your logical test inside an iferror function which returns false in case of error. [But be mindful of using it too generously](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-you-should-be-cautious-about-using-excels-iferror-formula/).

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Dummy1!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy1!$B$3:$B$2473,0))<>0,FALSE),
INDEX(Dummy1!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy1!$B$3:$B$2473,0)),
IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Dummy2!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy2!$B$3:$B$2473,0))<>0,FALSE),
INDEX(Dummy2!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy2!$B$3:$B$2473,0)),
INDEX(Dummy3!$A$3:$A$1048576,MATCH(B1,Dummy3!$B$3:$B$2473,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't any error handling in your formula - this will do it:

```
=IF(TRIM($B$2)="","Please enter value into B2",IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Dummy1!$A:$A,MATCH($B$2,Dummy1!$B:$B,0),1)<>0,INDEX(Dummy1!$A:$A,MATCH($B$2,Dummy1!$B:$B,0),1),IF(INDEX(Dummy2!$A:$A,MATCH($B$2,Dummy2!$B:$B,0),1)<>0,INDEX(Dummy2!$A:$A,MATCH($B$2,Dummy2!$B:$B,0),1),IF(INDEX(Dummy3!$A:$A,MATCH($B$2,Dummy3!$B:$B,0),1)<>0,INDEX(Dummy3!$A:$A,MATCH($B$2,Dummy3!$B:$B,0),1),"Not in any of the sheets"))),"Not in any of the sheets"))
```